# Surface integral, xyz coordinates

Tags: calculus, surface-integrals

I tried to solve the following integral and I get either $\frac\pi4$ or $\frac\pi8$. Can't figure out which is right.

$$\iint_Sxz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz+x^2y\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dz+y^2z\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$

where $S$ is the surface $x^2+y^2\le1$, $x\ge0$, $y\ge0$, and $0\le z\le x^2+y^2$.

I used Gauss's theorem:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're wondering whether you made a mistake, it would help greatly if you included your work.

Comment: Better to add what you"ve tried.

Comment: Once you've added what you've tried, people will be able to point out where exactly you might have erred..

Comment: You have $dx\,dz$ rather than the usual $dz\,dx$ in the middle term. Have you appropriately put a negative sign in the vector field in that term? Also, please explain how you've described a surface. It sounds like a volume to me.

Comment: Integral on surface is specific type of multiple integral - from where you take definition?

Comment: You should answer my complaints. You did *not* specify the surface. You specified a volume. And, moreover, you did *not* watch out for the negative sign on $Q$. In general, if you expect some response or help, you should in turn respond to *our* questions.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I don't understand what you mean. I used Gauss's theorem as I wrote in the question. I can add a picture of the formula I used. Also, here is a link to the same integral with a bit different surface, and the answer is π/8, which makes me think here it can't be also π/8. http://istu-pmi.narod.ru/img/261.gif

Comment: Your $z$ bounds are wrong. What do your inequalities say the real boundaries should be?

Comment: @NinadMunshi, thank you but I already found the answer elsewhere. Indeed I had the upper bound of z wrong. The correect bound is r^2. Thank you.